# Непонятные объявления для функции быстрой сортировки

Tags: c++, сортировка, qsort

Почему у `std::qsort` два объявления? Что означают эти непонятные типы?

```
void qsort( void *ptr, std::size_t count, std::size_t size, /*compare-pred*/* comp );
void qsort( void *ptr, std::size_t count, std::size_t size, /*c-compare-pred*/* comp );

extern "C++" using /*compare-pred*/ = int(const void*, const void*); // exposition-only
extern "C" using /*c-compare-pred*/ = int(const void*, const void*); // exposition-only
```

Взято отсюда https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort.

А в русской версии ещё и другие объявления https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort:

```
extern "C" void qsort( void *ptr, std::size_t count, std::size_t size,
            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
extern "C++" void qsort( void *ptr, std::size_t count, std::size_t size,
            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
```

Почему, если посмотреть объявление функции в реализации msvc, там оно только одно?

Comment: @user7860670 последний, почему их 2, почему по-разному на разных языках

Comment: @user7860670 ну я же привёл все объявления в вопросе... последний = самый правый, 4 если считать слева, первый если считать справа...

Comment: @user7860670 у нас по-разному отображаются вопросы? или я не понимаю, о чём вы спрашиваете? `/*compare-pred*/* comp` и `/*c-compare-pred*/* comp` последние параметры

Comment: @Стаss, `Две перегрузки, предоставленные стандартной библиотекой C++ различны, так как типы параметра comp различны (языковое связывание является частью типа) `

Comment: За что минусы вопросу не понимаю?

Comment: @Стass, минусы не мои, но вероятно они за то, что не понятно о чём именно вопрос и что именно не понятно...

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения стандарта два типа функций с разным *языковым связыванием* (*language linkage*, то, что задаётся `extern "Foo"`) являются разными типами. С практической стороны обоснование такого требования — у них могут быть разные соглашения о вызовах (дабы дать возможность реализациям предоставлять поддержку других языков, например, `extern "Fortran"`). При этом для Си никаких оговорок нет, так что, вообще говоря, на сферической реализации в вакууме вызывать через указатель вида `void (*f)()` функцию объявленную с `extern "C"` нельзя.

Видимо, чтобы подчеркнуть то, что `qsort`'у можно передавать и функции с Си-связыванием и с C++-связываем, в стандарте и оговорились, что она должна быть объявлена в двух версиях. Но практически во всех реализациях соглашения о вызовах для Си и C++ не отличаются. Так что смысла искусственно создавать эти различия и плодить сущности на практике нет, так что большинство просто  объявление `qsort`'а проcто берётся из хедеров libc.

Как-то так.

Comment: компилятор в Oracle Studio - едиственный из известных мне, где указатели на функции с разным language linkage имеют разные типы

Comment: @Cubbi, приветствую, видел твой комментарий в истории ревизий на cppreference, но сначала не понял, что это про старый добрый `suncc`... сейчас посмотрел версию 12.6 под linux — там точно также используется системный glibc'шный хедер... я так понимаю, дело было под солярой? и не помнишь версию?

Comment: Да. See also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2316 и https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6277